# Xamarin ios: ABAddressbook.Create always null, can't request access

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, abaddressbook

I have a problem with requesting access to the Addressbook, because ABAddressbook.Create is always null.

So how can I request the Access?

```
NSError err = new NSError ();
ABAddressBook ab = ABAddressBook.Create(out err)
ab.RequestAccess (delegate {}); //ab always null
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: NSError err = new NSError ();
using(ABAddressBook ab = ABAddressBook.Create(out err)) {
ab.RequestAccess (delegate {});
} // USED AFTER DISPOSED, What da hell?! :(

Comment: are you getting a value in err?

Comment: yes "ABAddressBookErrorDomain error 1."

Answer (score 6):

If it's `null` then something was wrong and your `NSError` should tell you what it is (btw there's no need to initialize an `out` parameter).

In general (iOS6+) your code should look like:

```
NSError err; 
var ab = ABAddressBook.Create (out err);
if (err != null) {
    // process error
    return;
}
// if the app was not authorized then we need to ask permission
if (ABAddressBook.GetAuthorizationStatus () != ABAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) { 
    ab.RequestAccess (delegate (bool granted, NSError error) { 
        if (error != null) {
            // process error
        } else if (granted) {
            // permission now granted -> use the address book
        } 
    }); 
} else { 
    // permission already granted -> use the address book
}
```

Comment: From Apple doc -> `kABOperationNotPermittedByUserError`. Is is possible the application has already be refused access by the device user ? If it was go check your settings to re-enable it.

Comment: yes once I got it, I answered with no for testing. But If I delete the app, he remembers my decision anyway for all the time?

Comment: ok its seems so, I can live with that and check only the AuthorizationStatus ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my formula for dealing with this situation.

```
private void RequestAddressBookAccess ()
{
    NSError error;
    ABAddressBook addressBook = ABAddressBook.Create (out error);
    if (error != null || addressBook == null)
        ShowAddressBookAccessInstructions ();

    else if (ABAddressBook.GetAuthorizationStatus () != ABAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) {
        addressBook.RequestAccess (delegate(bool granted, NSError err) {
            if (granted && err == null)
                this.InvokeOnMainThread (() => DoStuff (addressBook));
            else 
                ShowAddressBookAccessInstructions ();
        });
    } else
        DoStuff (addressBook);
}

private void ShowAddressBookAccessInstructions ()
{
    UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView ("Cannot Access Contacts",
        "Go to Settings -> Privacy -> Contacts and allow this app to access your contacts to use this functionality",
        null, "Ok", null);
    alert.Show();
}
```

Comment: Some better error handling is warranted, but that's up to how you want to handle it.